# Trouble with Timer 0

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, timers, avrdude, avr-gcc

I'm taking my first wobbly steps outside the Arduino IDE and I'm not having much success with timers / interrupts. I can set a pin to output and light an LED with registers fine but I cannot for the life of me get it to blink using a timer. I have tried numerous tutorials and followed the Atmel ATmega328 datasheet very closely.

Using an Arduino Uno R3 & Atmel ICE (ISP.) My dev system is Raspbian (Debian) with the GNU AVR toolchain (avr-gcc, avr-objcopy, avrdude.) Apart from not having a bootloader it's a bog standard board (including fuses.)

Here's my current code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    PORTB ^= (1 << PB5); // Toggle Arduino Pin #13
}

int main (void)
{
    DDRB = (1 << DDB5); // Arduino Pin #13 is Output

    cli(); // Clear Interrupts

    OCR0A = (unsigned char)0xFF; // Compare Register A = 255
    TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0A); // Enable Interrupt for Comp. Reg. A
    TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01); // CTC Mode

    sei(); // Set Interrupts
    TCCR0B = (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00); // Divide by 1024 Prescaler (GO!)

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if I'm just not seeing something or if I've set registers in the wrong order but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: doesn't `return 0` reset the device? Try `while(1);` to make it wait indefinitely.

Comment: I am going to scream. Thank you!
(Do you do the Answer Question thing or do I?)

Comment: The commenter should convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return 0` resets the device. Use `while(1);` instead, to make it wait indefinitely.

Comment: Just to clarify, doing a return from `main` does **not** reset the device, as I showed in my answer. I mention this in case people read this answer and think that returning from `main` is an easy way of achieving a device reset.

Answer (score 4):

Returning from `main` does not reset the device (it would start up again and do it all over in that case). It calls `exit` which turns interrupts off and loops indefinitely.

```
00000068 <__ctors_end>:
  68:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  6a:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  6c:   cf ef           ldi r28, 0xFF   ; 255
  6e:   d8 e0           ldi r29, 0x08   ; 8
  70:   de bf           out 0x3e, r29   ; 62
  72:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61
  74:   0e 94 52 00     call    0xa4    ; 0xa4 <main>
  78:   0c 94 61 00     jmp 0xc2    ; 0xc2 <_exit>

...

000000a4 <main>:
  a4:   80 e2           ldi r24, 0x20   ; 32
  a6:   84 b9           out 0x04, r24   ; 4
  a8:   f8 94           cli
  aa:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  ac:   87 bd           out 0x27, r24   ; 39
  ae:   82 e0           ldi r24, 0x02   ; 2
  b0:   80 93 6e 00     sts 0x006E, r24
  b4:   84 bd           out 0x24, r24   ; 36
  b6:   78 94           sei
  b8:   85 e0           ldi r24, 0x05   ; 5
  ba:   85 bd           out 0x25, r24   ; 37
  bc:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
  be:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  c0:   08 95           ret

000000c2 <_exit>:
  c2:   f8 94           cli

000000c4 <__stop_program>:
  c4:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xc4 <__stop_program>
```

You can see at address 0x74 it calls main, and then jumps to exit. `exit` turns off interrupts.

With interrupts off your ISR will not toggle pin 13.